# Combobox with textbox inside it in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, filter, combobox, textbox

I created a combo box that has a text box inside. Now I want it to filter the corresponding items for me when I type in the text box. How can I do this?

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,10,27" Name="comboBox3" > 
    <TextBox Name="text2" Width="90" TextChanged="text2_TextChanged" 
             Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}"></TextBox>
    <ComboBoxItem >salam</ComboBoxItem >
    <ComboBoxItem >khobi</ComboBoxItem >
    <ComboBoxItem>سلام</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>خوبی</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>عرض ادب</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>سپاسگذارم</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>مرسی</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Code:

```
private void text2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int c = comboBox3.Items.Count;
    MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
    object[] st = new object[c];

    List<string> listsource = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox3.Items[i].ToString());
        // listsource.Add(ComboBox3.Items.IndexOf(ComboBox3.SelectedItem));
        // listsource.Add(comboBox3.Items[i].ToString());
        // foreach (ComboBoxItem cbi in comboBox3.Items)
    }

    comboBox2.ItemsSource = listsource;
}
```

Comment: You've considered just seting IsEditable="True" on a regular unaltered combobox?

Comment: But I want to have a text box inside my combo box to search and filter items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a `TextBox`. If you set `IsEditable="True"` on the `ComboBox` then you can type a search term directly in the `ComboBox`.

To filter items handle `KeyUp` event on the `ComboBox`. `IsDropDownOpen` and `StaysOpenOnEdit` are set to true for testing purpose.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,10,27" Name="comboBox3"
IsEditable="True" IsDropDownOpen="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" KeyUp="comboBox3_KeyUp" > 
    <ComboBoxItem >salam</ComboBoxItem >
    <ComboBoxItem >khobi</ComboBoxItem >
    <ComboBoxItem>سلام</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>خوبی</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>عرض ادب</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>سپاسگذارم</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>مرسی</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind

```
private void comboBox3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var defaultView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(comboBox3.Items);

    var searchTerm = comboBox3.Text;
    defaultView.Filter = (item) =>
    {
        var comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)item;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || ((string)comboBoxItem.Content).Contains(searchTerm))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
    defaultView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Of course. But I want to have a text box inside my combo box to search and filter items. How can I do that?